# Uniform boundedness principle and convergence of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am reading 'A Panorama of Harmonic Analysis" by S. Krantz, and on page 67, he writes; ($D_N$ here denotes the Dirichlet kernel)

> The point of the last paragraph is worth belaboring. For each $N$, let $\phi_N(t)$ be the function that equals +1 when $D_N(t)\geq0$ and equals -1 when $D_N(t)<0$. Of course $\phi_N(t)$ is discontinuous. But now let $\psi_N(t)$ be a continuous function, bounded in absolute vale by 1, which agrees with $\phi_N$ except in a very small interval about each point where $\phi_N$ changes sign. Integrate $D_N$ against $\psi_N$. The calculation alluded at the start of the section then shows that the value of the integral is about $c\cdot\log N$, even though $\psi_N$ has supremum norm 1. **The uniform boundedness principle now tells us that convergence for partial summation in norm fails dramatically for continuous functions on the circle group.**

I'm having trouble understanding that last sentence. What does he mean by 'fails dramatically'? How is the uniform boundedness principle used here?

Let us denote the circle group by $\mathbb{T}$ and let $S_N f(t)$ be the $N$th partial sum of the Fourier series of a given function $f:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

Does he mean that the family of continuous functions (on the circle group) which $S_N f(t)$ does not converges to $f$ in uniform norm, is dense in $C(\mathbb{T})$?

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have the book of Krantz.
Anyway, I think that the point is the following (you can find a detailed explanation in Rudin, R&CA, pp. 100-103).

Consider the linear functionals
$$
L_N \colon C(\mathbb{T}) \to \mathbb{R},
\qquad
L_N f := S_N f (0).
$$
(Here we consider the point $x=0$, but any other point does the job.)

The computation you refer to tells us that
$$
\| L_N \| = \| D_N \|_1 \sim c \cdot \log N \to +\infty.
$$
But then, from the uniform boundedness principle, it follows that
$$
\sup_N |S_N f (0) | = +\infty
$$
for every $f$ in some dense $G_\delta$-set in $C(\mathbb{T})$.